# Drawing a square with "." and " " only in Python

Tags: python, size, spaces

I am trying to make a square with spaces and dots only, but I am having an issue.
I need to make the code in that way, so I can change the size of the square in just 1 input for each parameter. I am having issues with the "sides" variable how can I make the space between left side and right side automated by just giving only 1 input value.

```
def square_shape(top,sides,bottom):
            top = ". "*top
            sides =((".")+("     .\n"))*sides
            bottom = ". "*bottom
            print top
            print sides,bottom
        square_shape(8,7,8)
```

P.S With this code it works perfectly fine, but when I change the size of top and bottom , the space needed is not created in the sides.
I hope I was clear.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the space being dependent on length of square and don't use `\n` in the string or else your last line will also print a newline -

```
def square_shape(leng): # no need to use 3 variables
        print (". "*leng)
        for _ in range(leng-2):
            print (". " + "  " * (leng - 2) + ".")
        print (". "*leng)
square_shape(8)
```

Output -

```
. . . . . . . . 
.             .
.             .
.             .
.             .
.             .
.             .
. . . . . . . .
```

Comment: That's perfect but I haven't learned the (.join) method yet and I am having a mid-term next week, so I don't know if it would be a problem if I use it. Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
def square_shape(size):
    print '. ' * size + '.'
    print ('.' + '  ' * (size-1) + ' .\n') * (size-1),
    print '. ' * size + '.'
```

Comment: @Bendik This won't print a perfect square, there'll be a newline after the before the last line.

Comment: Now its a perfect square, of area size*size, fixed the number of rows just now.

Answer (score 0):

little bit optimized!

```
square_shape = int(input())
print ("."*square_shape)
for _ in range(square_shape-2):
    print ("."+ " "*(square_shape-2) + ".")
print ("."*square_shape)
```